# mysql data export for specific value using python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to get specific rows of data from mysql database table1. I'm looking wherever a certain id shows up in one of the columns.

I am having trouble with my code in the SELECT WHERE statement under 'query'. When i ask for a specific id (id_2_lookup) I get the entire table exported. where am I going wrong?

```
# Establish a MySQL connection
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from python_mysql_dbconfig import read_db_config
db_config = read_db_config()
conn = MySQLConnection(**db_config)
cursor = conn.cursor()

#to export to excel
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

#to get the datetime functions
import datetime
from datetime import datetime


#creates the workbook
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('imheretoo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

#formatting definitions
bold    = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'})
timeShape =  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'


query = ("SELECT sent_time, delivered_time, customer_name, id1_active, id2_active, id3_active, id1_inactive, id2_inactive, id3_inactive, location_active, location_inactive FROM table1 ")
"WHERE id1_active  '%s'"
id_2_lookup = [input('Who are you looking for:'),0]




# Execute sql Query
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall()


#sets up the header row
worksheet.write('A1','sent_time',bold)
worksheet.write('B1', 'delivered_time',bold)
worksheet.write('C1', 'customer_name',bold)
worksheet.write('D1', 'id1_active',bold)
worksheet.write('E1', 'id2_active',bold)
worksheet.write('F1', 'id3_active',bold)
worksheet.write('G1', 'id1_inactive',bold)
worksheet.write('H1', 'id2_inactive',bold)
worksheet.write('I1', 'id3_inactive',bold)
worksheet.write('J1', 'location_active',bold)
worksheet.write('K1', 'location_inactive',bold)
worksheet.autofilter('A1:K1')



print("sent_time", "delivered_time", "customer_name", "id1_active", "id2_active", "id3_active", "id1_inactive", "id2_inactive", "id3_inactive", "location_active", "location_inactive")
for row in result:
    print(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9],row[10])

# Create a For loop to iterate through each row in the XLS file, starting at row 2 to skip the headers
for r, row in enumerate(result, start=1):  #where you want to start printing results inside workbook
    for c, col in enumerate(row):
        worksheet.write_datetime(r,0,row[0], date_format)
        worksheet.write_datetime(r,1, row[1], date_format)
        worksheet.write(r,2, row[2])
        worksheet.write(r,3, row[3])
        worksheet.write(r,4, row[4])
        worksheet.write(r,5, row[5])
        worksheet.write(r,6, row[6])
        worksheet.write(r,7, row[7])
        worksheet.write(r,8, row[8])
        worksheet.write(r,9, row[9])
        worksheet.write(r,10, row[10])




#close out everything and save
cursor.close()
workbook.close()
conn.close()

#print number of rows and bye-bye message
print ("- - - - - - - - - - - - -")
rows = len(result)
print ("I just imported "+ str(rows) + " rows from MySQL!")
print ("")
print ("Good to Go!!!")
print ("")
```

---

I want to give you all the information I have with all the other files and what I'm shooting for to see if you can replicate and actually get it working just to see if it's not just my system or some configuration I have..

I have a database with one table.Lets call it ‘table1’ The table is broken down with columns like this:

sent_time | delivered_time |id1_active |id2_active |id3_active |id1_inactive |id2_inactive |id3_inactive |location_active |location_inactive …..`lots more

Lets say that these are two or more customers delivering goods to and from each other. Each customer has three id#s.

I created a ‘config.ini’ file to make my life a bit easier

```
[mysql]
host = localhost
database = db_name
user = root
password = blahblah
```

I created a ‘python_mysql_dbconfig.py’

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

def read_db_config(filename=’config.ini’, section=’mysql’):
“”” Read database configuration file and return a dictionary object
:param filename: name of the configuration file
:param section: section of database configuration
:return: a dictionary of database parameters
“””
# create parser and read ini configuration file
parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read(filename)

# get section, default to mysql
db = {}
if parser.has_section(section):
items = parser.items(section)
for item in items:
db[item[0]] = item[1]
else:
raise Exception(‘{0} not found in the {1} file’.format(section, filename))

return db
```

I now have the code we've been working on but now updated with what changes we had made but am still getting errors...

```
# Establish a MySQL connection
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from python_mysql_dbconfig import read_db_config
db_config = read_db_config()
conn = MySQLConnection(**db_config)
cursor = conn.cursor()

#to export to excel
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

#to get the datetime functions
import datetime
from datetime import datetime


#creates the workbook
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('imheretoo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

#formatting definitions
bold    = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'})
timeShape =  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

#actual query

id_2_lookup= [input('Who are you looking for:'),0]

query = (
    """SELECT sent_time, delivered_time, customer_name, id1_active, id2_active, id3_active, id1_inactive, id2_inactive, id3_inactive, location_active, location_inactive FROM table1 "
    "WHERE id1_active = %s""",(id_2_lookup)
)

# Execute sql Query

query = query % id_2_lookup
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall()



#sets up the header row
worksheet.write('A1','sent_time',bold)
worksheet.write('B1', 'delivered_time',bold)
worksheet.write('C1', 'customer_name',bold)
worksheet.write('D1', 'id1_active',bold)
worksheet.write('E1', 'id2_active',bold)
worksheet.write('F1', 'id3_active',bold)
worksheet.write('G1', 'id1_inactive',bold)
worksheet.write('H1', 'id2_inactive',bold)
worksheet.write('I1', 'id3_inactive',bold)
worksheet.write('J1', 'location_active',bold)
worksheet.write('K1', 'location_inactive',bold)
worksheet.autofilter('A1:K1')



print("sent_time", "delivered_time", "customer_name", "id1_active", "id2_active", "id3_active", "id1_inactive", "id2_inactive", "id3_inactive", "location_active", "location_inactive")
for row in result:
    print(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9],row[10])

# Create a For loop to iterate through each row in the XLS file, starting at row 2 to skip the headers
for r, row in enumerate(result, start=1):  #where you want to start printing results inside workbook
    for c, col in enumerate(row):
        worksheet.write_datetime(r,0,row[0], date_format)
        worksheet.write_datetime(r,1, row[1], date_format)
        worksheet.write(r,2, row[2])
        worksheet.write(r,3, row[3])
        worksheet.write(r,4, row[4])
        worksheet.write(r,5, row[5])
        worksheet.write(r,6, row[6])
        worksheet.write(r,7, row[7])
        worksheet.write(r,8, row[8])
        worksheet.write(r,9, row[9])
        worksheet.write(r,10, row[10])




#close out everything and save
cursor.close()
workbook.close()
conn.close()

#print number of rows and bye-bye message
print ("- - - - - - - - - - - - -")
rows = len(result)
print ("I just imported "+ str(rows) + " rows from MySQL!")
print ("")
print ("Good to Go!!!")
print ("")
```

Comment: Your where clause isn't actually part of your query. Try printing out your query to make sure it's doing what you want.

Comment: You don't use at all the value in `id_2_lookup`. Print your query before querying for debug

Comment: ok. I'm really new at this...sorry. I think i set it up to print out my query please tell me if I'm doing it wrong                                                        query = """
SELECT sent_time, delivered_time, customer_name, id1_active, id2_active, id3_active, id1_inactive, id2_inactive, id3_inactive, location_active, location_inactive
FROM table1
WHERE id1_active  '%s'
"""
id_2_lookup = [input('Who are you looking for:'),0]


print(query)

Comment: That looks like it should print the query. However, as @TomRon pointed out, you're not using the value of `id_2_lookup`. Prior to your print statement add a line `query % (id_2_lookup,)`. That will insert the value of `id_2_lookup` at the `%s` in your query string.

Comment: @JCVanHamme I did what you told me and I got an error that reads this"Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Python34\lookup_id.py", line 36, in <module> cursor.execute(query) File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py",

Comment: line 515, in execute   self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 488, in cmd_query result =self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result raise errors.get_exception(packet) mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your

Comment: MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''%s'' at line 1

Comment: That's coming from the call to `cursor.execute`. It sounds like your replacement (`query % (id_2_lookup,)`) didn't work. What is being printed by the `print` statement?

Comment: I saw examples of putting in cursor.execute(query, (id_2_lookup)) but when i do that it gives me an error stating I'm not using all of my statements... it would seem that this kind of operation is pretty simple...where am I going wrong?

Comment: sorry...skipped your question for a sec. it's printing this: SELECT sent_time, delivered_time, customer_name, id1_active, id2_active, id3_active, id1_inactive, id2_inactive, id3_inactive, location_active, location_inactive FROM table1 WHERE id1_active '%s'

Comment: I think the execute statement expects a tuple as its second argument. If you make it `cursor.execute(query, (id_2_lookup, ))` does that change the error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lookup_id.py", line 36, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query, (id_2_lookup, ))

Comment: File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 503, in execute
    psub = _ParamSubstitutor(self._process_params(params))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 386, in _process_params
    "Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Comment: Ah, sorry. Try dropping the single quotes from your query string.

Comment: I dropped the ' ' around %s and now looks like this:query = ("SELECT sent_time, delivered_time, customer_name, id1_active, id2_active, id3_active, id1_inactive, id2_inactive, id3_inactive, location_active, location_inactive FROM table1 "
"WHERE id1_active %s")

id_2_lookup = [input('Who are you looking for:'),0]                                             ****************************************************************************************** But am still getting the same error

Comment: I think I see the issue. Lemme type up an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you originally posted, the where clause isn't actually being included as part of the query. What I didn't notice at first was that you're including the results of your `input` call in a list that you're then trying to feed to the `cursor.execute` call. That won't work since you only have one marker to replace in your query string. If we assume that the user is entering the value for `id1_active`, then I think you want the following:

```
query = (
    "SELECT sent_time, delivered_time, customer_name, id1_active, id2_active, id3_active, id1_inactive, id2_inactive, id3_inactive, location_active, location_inactive FROM table1 "
    "WHERE id1_active = %s"
)
id_2_lookup = input('Who are you looking for:')
# Execute sql Query
cursor.execute(query, (id_2_lookup, ))
```

This will try to match the user entered data against `id1_active`. Obviously, if that's not what you intended you'll have to adjust your query as necessary.

You could, in principle, insert the input values yourself and not rely on `cursor.execute` to do it for you. In that case,

```
query = (
    "SELECT sent_time, delivered_time, customer_name, id1_active, id2_active, id3_active, id1_inactive, id2_inactive, id3_inactive, location_active, location_inactive FROM table1 "
    "WHERE id1_active = %s"
)
id_2_lookup = input('Who are you looking for:')
# Execute sql Query
query = query % id_2_lookup
cursor.execute(query)
```

This will insert the value directly into the query so that `cursor.execute` only sees the query string and doesn't need to do any replacement. Generally speaking, though, your way is better.

Comment: does any of this make a difference if I'm using Python34?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lookup_id.py", line 37, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query, id_2_lookup)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 492, in execute
    stmt = operation.encode(self._connection.python_charset)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: I don't want to do anything with customer_name as of yet...just id1_active. so I modified your example to reflect this:                            query = (
    """SELECT sent_time, delivered_time, customer_name, id1_active, id2_active, id3_active, id1_inactive, id2_inactive, id3_inactive, location_active, location_inactive FROM table1 "
    "WHERE id1_active = %s""",(id_2_lookup)

Comment: if I do your second example I get this :

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lookup_id.py", line 37, in <module>
    query = query % id_2_lookup
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'list'

Comment: I edited my original question by adding as much detail at the bottom of it after the line of **************  I hope you could try to replicate everything that I'm doing and see if you can actually get it to work. The only extra thing you would have to build is a table in mysql with those column headers and just a few rows with information in them.

Comment: Nr int(11) AI PK 
sent_time datetime 
delivered_time datetime 
customer_name varchar(45) 
id1_active varchar(15) 
id2_active varchar(15) 
id3_active varchar(16) 
id1_inactive varchar(15) 
id2_inactive varchar(15) 
id3_inactive varchar(16) 
location_active varchar(45) 
location_inactive varchar(45)

Comment: I've edited my answer to match your stated assumptions, I think. Let's give this a try.

Comment: Now my next question would be: How hard would it be to lookup the same 'id_2_lookup' in multiple columns like all the id#_active and id#_inactive ones?

Comment: I answered it: query = (
    "SELECT sent_time, delivered_time, customer_name, id1_active, id2_active, id3_active, id1_inactive, id2_inactive, id3_inactive, location_active, location_inactive FROM table1 "
    "WHERE %s IN(id1_active, id2_active, id3_active, id1_inactive, id2_inactive, id3_inactive)"
)